# Matriz, no puedo asignar variables

Tags: java

Tengo una matriz [99][2] que me guarda los datos en un txt con numero de dos columnas , otra del mismo tamaño que asigna una variable por cada intervalo en que esten los numeros ex:
0 - 0.25 asigna la variable A y E respectivamente.
0.25 - 0.5 asigna la variable B y F
0.5 - 0.75 asigna la variable C y G,
0.75 - 1 asigna la variable D y H.
A B C D para la primera columna, y E F G H para la segunda, y al final me trae una cuenta de cuantas A's, B's, C's,....., D's se encontraron.
 mi problema esta en el intervalo 0.75 - 1.0, hé creado una variable SA ( sin asignar, para que guarde la cantidad de numeros que no estan en el rango. el cual si me trae los que deberia estar en D y H.
 matriz[][] almacena los numeros del txt, Variables[][] la uso para asignar las variables si se encuentran en el intervalo.
**Esta es una muestra de la salida del programa: 



A= 27

B= 22

C= 24

D= 0 

E= 27

F= 23

G= 24

H= 0

SA= 51**

El codigo con el que estoy trabajando es el siguiente:

```
for(int filas=0;filas<matriz.length;filas++){          
       for(int columnas=0;columnas<matriz[filas].length;columnas++){

           if((matriz[filas][0]>0)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.25)){
                    variables[filas][0]="A";
                    A++;                                
           } else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.25)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.5)) {    
                    variables[filas][0]="B";
                    B++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.5)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.75)) {
                    variables[filas][0]="C";
                    C++;
           }else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.1)) {
                    variables[filas][0]="D";
                    D++;
           } else {
               variables[filas][0]= "sin asignar";
               SA++;
           }

           if((matriz[filas][1]>0)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.25)){
               variables[filas][1]="E";
                    E++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.25)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.5)) {
               variables[filas][1]="F";
               F++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.5)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.75)) {
               variables[filas][1]="G";     
               G++;
           }else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.1)) {             
               variables[filas][1]="H";
               H++;
           } else {
               variables[filas][1]= "sin asignar";
               SA++;
           }
```

Tengo otro ciclo parecido que me lleva la cuenta de las variable A - E ....D - H si estan en la misma fila pero lo mismo. ya que no hay varaiable D ni H, no me muestra nada para las combinaciones de estas variables.
Quedo agradecido si pueden echarme una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo mal la ultima comprobación. Estas comprobando el rango [0.75, 0.1) el cual es ilogico. Lo que quieres comprobar es [0.75, 1) por lo que para solucionarlo hay que cambiar tus 0.1 por 1

Cambia

```
}else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.1)) {
```

por

```
}else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][0]<1)) {
```

Y tambien

```
}else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.1)) {
```

por

```
}else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][1]<1)) {
```

Tu código debe quedar así:

```
for(int filas=0;filas<matriz.length;filas++){          
       for(int columnas=0;columnas<matriz[filas].length;columnas++){

           if((matriz[filas][0]>0)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.25)){
                    variables[filas][0]="A";
                    A++;                                
           } else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.25)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.5)) {    
                    variables[filas][0]="B";
                    B++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.5)&&(matriz[filas][0]<0.75)) {
                    variables[filas][0]="C";
                    C++;
           }else if((matriz[filas][0]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][0]<1)) {
                    variables[filas][0]="D";
                    D++;
           } else {
               variables[filas][0]= "sin asignar";
               SA++;
           }

           if((matriz[filas][1]>0)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.25)){
               variables[filas][1]="E";
                    E++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.25)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.5)) {
               variables[filas][1]="F";
               F++;
           } else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.5)&&(matriz[filas][1]<0.75)) {
               variables[filas][1]="G";     
               G++;
           }else if((matriz[filas][1]>=0.75)&&(matriz[filas][1]<1)) {               
               variables[filas][1]="H";
               H++;
           } else {
               variables[filas][1]= "sin asignar";
               SA++;
           }
```

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente ese era el error. increible como un pequeño detalle puede tomar Horas de estress xDxD

Comment: De nada, a mi me han pasado cosas asi a montones ;)